# Mailchimp API First and Last Name not working merge_fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to add new members to mailchimp using it's API and express(node.js). I am just learning node.js too. My js code is:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const var1 = req.body.email;
  const va2 = req.body.finame;
  const va3 = req.body.laname;
  var data = {
    members: [
      {
        email_address: var1,
        status: "subscribed",
        merge_fields: {
          FNAME: va2,
           LNAME: va3
         }
      }
    ]
  };
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const url = "url";
  const options = {
    method: "POST", 
    auth:"username:api"
  };
  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
    response.on("data", function(data){
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    })
  });
  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();
});
```

As expected it adds a new member to my mailchimp but it doesn't add the first and last name with this error message:

```
new_members: [],
  updated_members: [],
  errors: [
    {
      email_address: 'example@gmail.com',       
      error: 'Your merge fields were invalid.',       
      error_code: 'ERROR_GENERIC',
      field: 'FNAME',
      field_message: 'Please enter a value'
    }
  ],
  total_created: 0,
  total_updated: 0,
  error_count: 1,
```

I have tried putting FNAME in quotation marks and that didn't work, I mean I didn't expect it to but just tired something. I checked the name for the variable and it wasn't the problem too. I have been trying to correct this for 2 days now.

Comment: Show how the `POST /` is done. Are you sure `req.body.finame` is set?

Comment: omg, I was changing the "id" for the input not the "name". I just realized that after console.logging the ```req.body.finame```. Thank you so much.